# How to "flip" an array?

Tags: c#, arrays, xna, flip

I have the following code:

```
BlockTypes[,] BackupQuad = EditModeBlocks.ListOfBlocks; //Create Backup

for (int x = 0; x < 16; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < 16; y++)
    {
        //Translate each point to the opposite side
        EditModeBlocks.ListOfBlocks[15 - x, y] = BackupQuad[x, y]; 
    }
}
```

First it makes up a backup (`BackupQuad`), and then it loops through each "block" in the backup array. And then it reads the block from the backup array and rewrites it to the original array as 15 - X. (I tried 16 - x too, but didnt work). It works for the most part, but it copies one half to the other side, deleting everything there.
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> First it makes up a backup (BackupQuad)

No, it really doesn't. That just takes a copy of the *reference*. If you want to take a copy of the actual *object*, you have to do so explicitly. For example:

```
BlockTypes[,] BackupQuad = (BlockTypes[,]) EditModeBlocks.ListOfBlocks.Clone();
```

Comment: Amazing. Is it like that just with arrays, or with other data types as well? Because I thought you had to explicitly say that you wanted a reference?

Comment: @leaf68: No, it's all reference types (classes, interfaces, delegates,  arrays). This is fundamental to understanding C#. See http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/references.html for more details.

Comment: Ok, so how would I copy a class in the same way that you copied the array?

Comment: @leaf68: It depends on the class - there's no "general purpose" copy; it has to support it itself.